# color and icon preview extension in VSCode for Flutter

Tags: visual-studio-code, dart, flutter

I'am using Visual Studio Code for Flutter Developing and i really like to have a feature that exist in Intelij IDE Which it is showing the **Color of Color's Name** and showing the **Icon of the Icon's Name** beside the code like in the picture ..
[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vrigA.png)

I've found many extensions but it not supporting dart ..

Comment: try creating an issue here https://github.com/Dart-Code/Dart-Code/issues

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### (Updated Answer)

These are now available in the Flutter VS Code extension and enabled by default:

[image: Flutter gutter icons in VS Code]

[image: Flutter colour previews in VS Code]

#### (Original Answer)

This is not currently supported in the Dart/Flutter plugins for VS Code. However as a workaround the tooltips for the colours/icons should show previews in their descriptions.

To implement it in VS Code requires some supporting changes in the Dart/Flutter SDKs. If you want to be notified when there's progress on this, click the Subscribe button on https://github.com/Dart-Code/Dart-Code/issues/807 (also add a Thumbs Up if you'd really like to see it to help use prioritise open issues).

Comment: This has been delivered.  It may not be perfect, but does work sometimes.